# saving character vector so that output file shows regex special characters

Tags: r, regex, string, readr

I have a character vector which includes `regex` special characters such as `\n`.
I want to save this vector to a txt-file which shows the `\n`.

The code below creates a txt file, but when opening the file e.g. in notepad, the `\n` are translated into linebreaks. I don't want to see the linebreaks, I want to see `\n`.

```
library(tidyverse)
my_text <- "hello\n, nice to meet you.\n\n. how are you?"
my_text
readr::write_file(my_text, "my_text.txt")
```

this is what notepad shows:

```
hello
, nice to meet you.

. how are you?
```

but I want to see

```
"hello\n, nice to meet you.\n\n. how are you?"
```

I thought there was some kind of 'raw option', but seems like I am wrong. Thx!

Comment: So, `my_text <- "hello\\n, nice to meet you.\\n\\n. how are you?"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
many thanks. sorry, should have been clearer in my question. I am aware of escaping backlashes etc. when eg. searching the text with stringr/stringi etc. I was wondering whether there is some kind of save/write command which takes care of the need to escape e.g. backlashes when actually saving the vector to a file.

Comment: Do you mean something like `stringi::stri_escape_unicode(my_text)`?